# How to indicate that user needs to tab out of a field for search to trigger

Tags: filter, textbox

I have added couple of text boxes to filter columns based on values and we trigger a search once the user enters a value and tabs out of the field. Sometimes the user presses the enter action to trigger, how do I give a visual cue that he needs to tab and not enter. Appreciate inputs

Answer (score 3):

I think you're approaching the event from the wrong perspective. In your research, you have found that users perform a specific task in a certain way. Perhaps they have a good reason to do it that way. Why try to change their behaviour instead of updating your system to support both ways?

In some cases it makes sense to run inline checks after the user stops typing. Make sure you add enough clues to make the current task and its status obvious by adding visual cues.

Answer (score 1):

You could offer your users multiple ways to accomplish the same task, why not enable the enter-trigger while also keeping the tab-trigger?

Either way, enter or tab, both options are not really transparent, you should also provide a visual cue to let the user know what his action is causing, so a button with a label like "Apply", would make it more transparent.